# I'm looking for any canonical method on how to solve a nasty differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algorithms

Now, I do know how to guess and get a solution (as apparently there is a theorem that states guessing is a valid method).

However, I am curious if anyone knows of an algotithm for solving the equations of the form:

$$ay'' + b\lfloor x \rfloor y' + c\lfloor x \rfloor^2 y = 0$$

where $y = f(x)$ for some $f$ and where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are nonzero constants.

Now I know that technically this has no nontrivial solutions because of sharp corners, nondifferentiability, etc. I believe that the term weak solution or solutions to the corresponding integral equations likely captures what Im asking for. It seems like whenever I bring up something like this people give different names and this isnt really a question that needs an argument over terminology.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** On any interval $I_n = (n, n+1)$, we have a homogeneous equation with constant coefficients. The solution is a linear combination of two complex exponentials.

Once this part is solved, see which conditions are needed on the constants to satisfy the equation at point $x = n$ in the sense of the distributions.

**Edit**
One way to see the initial equation $\left(E\right)$ is to write down the
first order system

\begin{equation}{\left[\begin{array}{c}y\\
z
\end{array}\right]'} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\
{-\frac{c}{a}} {\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor }^{2}&{-\frac{b}{a}} \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor 
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}y\\
z
\end{array}\right] := A \left(x\right) \left[\begin{array}{c}y\\
z
\end{array}\right]\end{equation}

where the first component of $Y = \left[\begin{array}{c}y\\
z
\end{array}\right]$ is  the
solution of $\left(E\right)$. Here $A (x)$ is a piecewise constant,
locally bounded matrix. One cannot multiply such a matrix by any
distribution, but if we restrict ourselves to locally integrable
distributions $Y \in  {L}_{\text{loc}}^{1}$, then $A \left(x\right) Y$ has a sense
as a locally integrable function and we can ask that $\left(1\right)$ be
satisfied in the sense of the distributions, which means that
for all ${\varphi} , {\psi} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{\infty }$,
\begin{equation}{-\int_{}^{}\left({{\varphi}'} y+{{\psi}'} z\right) d x} = \int_{}^{}\left({\varphi} z-\frac{c}{a} {\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor }^{2} {\psi} y-\frac{b}{a} \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  {\psi} z\right) d x\end{equation}

Skipping a few details it is easy to prove that $y$ is a
solution in the classical sense of
$a {y''}+n b {y'}+{n}^{2} c y = 0$ in the open
interval ${I}_{n} = \left(n , n+1\right)$, because in such intervals,
${y'} , {z'} \in  {L}_{\text{loc}}^{1} \Rightarrow  y , z \in  {\mathcal{C}}^{0} \Rightarrow  {y'} , {z'} \in  {\mathcal{C}}^{0}$ etc.
We denote by ${y}_{n}$ this
solution, which is a smooth function on
$\overline{{I}_{n}} = \left[n , n+1\right]$

To find the boundary conditions, we compute

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  \begin{array}{rcll}\displaystyle -\int_{{I}_{n}}^{}\left({{\varphi}'} y+{{\psi}'} z\right) d x&=&{\varphi} \left(n\right) {y}_{n} \left(n\right)&{-{\varphi}} \left(n+1\right) {y}_{n} \left(n+1\right)+{\psi} \left(n\right) {z}_{n} \left(n\right)-{\psi} \left(n+1\right) {z}_{n} \left(n+1\right)\\
&&&\displaystyle +\int_{{I}_{n}}^{}\left({\varphi} {{y_n}'}+{\psi} {{z_n}'}\right) d x\\
&=&{\varphi} \left(n\right) {y}_{n} \left(n\right)&{-{\varphi}} \left(n+1\right) {y}_{n} \left(n+1\right)+{\psi} \left(n\right) {z}_{n} \left(n\right)-{\psi} \left(n+1\right) {z}_{n} \left(n+1\right)\\
&&&\displaystyle +\int_{I_n}^{}\left({\varphi} z_n-\frac{c}{a} {\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor }^{2} {\psi} {y}_{n}-\frac{b}{a} \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  {\psi} {z}_{n}\right) d x
\end{array}$$

Summing on $n$ gives

$$0 = \sum _{n \in  \mathbb{Z}} \left({\varphi} \left(n\right) \left({y}_{n} \left(n\right)-{y}_{n-1} \left(n\right)\right)+{\psi} \left(n\right) \left({z}_{n} \left(n\right)-{z}_{n-1} \left(n\right)\right)\right)$$

We see that the condition is simply the continuity of $y$
and ${y'}$ at the integer points $x = n$.

Now I think you have all the tools to reach a complete solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly your request, you are looking for an algorithm to compute the
solution to the ode
$$
ay'' + b\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor y' + c\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ^{\,2} y = 0
$$

If so,  consider that such an equation
corresponds to that governing a series RLC circuit

[image: Ode_Floor_1]

$$
L\,q'' + R\,q' + {1 \over C}q = 0
$$
where $q(t)$ represents the electric charge on the capacitor, and 
$i(t) ={{dq(t)}/{dt}}$ is the current flowing in the circuit.

So, passing from $x$ to $t$ just to keep congruent with the physical model,
we are dealing with a circuit which has a constant inductance, while its resistance and capacitance 
are varying with time
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  L\, = const. = a \hfill \cr 
  R = b\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor  \hfill \cr 
  C = 1/\left( {c\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor ^{\,2} } \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
with changes occurring "instantaneously", at discrete values of time $t=n \;|\,n \in \mathbb N_0$, while they remain constant during the following interval.

The [behaviour of the RLC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit)
when the parameters are fixed is well studied and known,
and mathematically established also for negative values of $R$ and/or $L$ and/or$C$,
and it is not the case to repeat the fundamentals here.
But it is worthy to note that we can fix $L$ to be in any case positive; this physically means that
the "inertia" of the inductor will assure that $q''(t)$ be limited in absolute value,  **so that $q(t)$ and $q'(t)$ remain continuous** at the change of $R$ and $C$,
(while $q''(t)$ will change abruptely to keep the voltage balance).

That is essentially the base of the algorithm to follow:
 - the initial values $q(0),q'(0)$ will determine the solution of the ode $q_0(t)$ for $0 \le t <1$
(with $R = b\left\lfloor 0 \right\rfloor=0$ and $1/C = c\left\lfloor 0 \right\rfloor^2=0$) ;
 -  $q_0(t \to 1),q'_0(t \to 1)$ will provide the initial values for the second piece $q_1(t)\; |\,1 \le t <2$
(solution of ode with $R$ and $1/C$ corresponding to $\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor=1$) ;
 .. and so on
thereby obtaining the solution piece-wise in time.

Comment: It seems like you've missed the fact that there are non-constant coefficients on the $y'$ and $y$ terms, so this equation is not a constant coefficient differential equation, while the RLC equations are.

Comment: @B.Mehta, note that the floor function remains constant during each piece of $1$ second ($n \le t < n+1$): the values of R and C are instantaneously varied every second and remain constant during the interval.

Comment: @GCab Ah, I missed the part where you obtain the solution piecewise - the edit clarifies nicely!